# Identify VHS about Judaism from the 80's

Tags: chagim-holidays

This video came out in the 80’s.  It was an introduction to Judaism.  Starts with creation, goes on to discuss all the holidays.  It featured a family explaining everything about Judaism.  I believe the video was intended for children primarily.  The “father” had a moustache.  In the seder segment the wife eats grated horseradish for maror, says that if you want to feel what it’s like to have fire in your mouth, this is what it feels like.  (Or something along these lines). Does anyone recognize this video and know the name of it?

Comment: דודו פישר? Dudu Fisher?

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tmYudOgdSmY

Comment: @kouty that doesn't resemble what i described in any way.